# Fix Insecure HTTP Methods on Web Servers

Tags: api, http, post, trace, http-options-method

my client is asking:
Following web server are exposed to a number of different methods to end users that can expose the web service to varying degrees of risk. Acceptable web methods are typically GET, POST and CONNECT (in the case of HTTPS).

• Server a • server b 
It is found that the OPTIONS HTTP method is available on the web servers The OPTIONS method allows an attacker to enumerate the available methods on the web servers which allow servers to accept the TRACE method and leave themselves vulnerable to HTTP TRACE Cross-Site Scripting vulnerability. This is because the TRACE method simply echoes the user-supplied input back to the end user.

Now how to disable this method , how to check these and will there be any downtime for this to change.
server is running centos

Answer (score 0):

first check Trace and options methods whether it is enable.

```
curl -i -X TRACE <URL>
curl -i -X OPTIONS <URL>
```

If http response is 200 then these methods are enable.

To disable and only to allow GET POST and CONNECT

The first thing to do is make sure that mod_rewrite is loaded.  If mod_rewrite.so is missing from your apache configuration but you have it installed, (and your install location is /usr/local/apache), then add the following statement to your httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule  rewrite_module  "/usr/local/apache/modules/mod_rewrite.so"
```

Then add the following as well to your httpd.conf file or within < virtualhost>...< /virtualhost>:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(GET|POST|CONNECT)
  RewriteRule .* - [F] 
</IfModule>
```

Or only to disable TRACE
For apache2 this can be done adding to the main httpd.conf file the following:

```
TraceEnable off
```

Restart apache